# Find price of unique user in Sequelize Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to convert this sql query into sequelize:
**SELECT SUM(price) FROM users where username in(SELECT DISTINCT(username) FROM users);**

```
Users.findAll({
    attributes: [
      // [Sequelize.literal('DISTINCT(username)'), 'username'],
      [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('price')), 'price'],
    ],
});
```

Here not able to apply where in Sequelize.fn.

Comment: Are you sure you want to sum `price` exactly from `users`? This query doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Yes, I need total price of all the users.

Comment: `where username in(SELECT DISTINCT(username) FROM users)` will be always true, isn't it?

Comment: This is returning unique usernames. I am able to execute this query on psql but need to convert into sequelize.

Comment: I mean if you don't have any conditions in `(SELECT DISTINCT(username) FROM users)` then you will get all usernames from `users` table and thus you will get all records in the main query